# Are portals ever deleted?

Tags: ingress

I'm pretty new to Ingress and I noticed there's a huge amount of portals in my city. I don't mind that much, I just wonder: **Are portals ever deleted for any reason?**

Comment: Yes, a portal near by got removed.  No clue what the reason was though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, portals can be deleted. [Recently in Germany all 2nd world war concentration camps have been cleared of portals.](http://www.wired.co.uk/news/archive/2015-07/03/google-ingress-apology-for-concentration-camp) This is a rather unusual case though. But portals can be deleted by reporting them.

If you feel a portal is against the rules (e.g. I have seen grass and standard road markings...), is removed from the real world or is in a dangerous location, you can report it to Niantic:

- In the scanner app by tapping on the image, then hit the "Edit" button at the bottom and then you'll find the option to "report invalid portal".
- On the [Google support page](https://support.google.com/ingress/) (might go away soon now that Niantic has departed from Google): Click "Contact Us" in the top right corner, then "Report an issue with a Portal or a Mission" and then select a reason.

While the portal is removed from the game world, I believe your stats (unique hacks & captures) will not be decreased.

Answer (score 3):

Here in town, we're doing a lot of construction.  With that construction, a lot of different portals have been removed, since the construction has displaced the historic marker for the portal and it's become impossible for anyone to use even foot traffic to get to these location, unless you were a construction worker.

I honestly don't know what the protocol is for submitting a portal to be removed, but it's happened here in my city and I'm sure it's happened elsewhere.  But for a fact of being deleted?  I doubt it would be totally deleted from everywhere.  But portals can, and have been, removed before.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It makes sense to remove the portal when its historic marker vanishes. Btw I had to find difference between "remove" and "delete". In my question I meant either deleted or removed, in the end it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Temporary art projects are another example where removing them makes sense. Of course not every local community wants portals to be removed, because a higher portal density is nice. So you will find a few in every larger town where the actual thing is not there any more. Street art can be cleared, temporary art can be removed, buildings demolished or Vodafone partnerships with Niantic can end. Also note that reporting is unfortunately sometimes used to mass-report someone's homeportal or a local blue/green community center portal to troll the other team.

Comment: Temporary art should not be submitted, but it often happen as it's not always obvious if an exhibition is temporary or permanent. I reported many cases but with not much success.